# When a speedster runs does everything become colder?

Tags: marvel, x-men, physics, x-men-days-of-future-past, quicksilver

So I was watching *X-Men: Days of Future Past*. In the prison break scene when Quicksilver deviates all the bullets, he first tastes whatever they were cooking in the kitchen. So it got me thinking, if his relative speed increases that means that the vibration of the particles on the soup (or whatever) become relatively slower. Since heat is strictly related to the vibration of the particles, does this mean that everything becomes colder relative to him?

Comment: Voting to reopen. The reason for closing states: "Questions seeking scientific solutions or explanations are off-topic ***unless related directly to a cited work of fiction***." The question is asking about the effects of a fictional superpower. It may be inspired by real-life science, but it certainly isn't satisfactorily answerable using real-world science.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish And how are we supposed to answer with in-universe physics only? In fact, we'd be using real-world physics to answer it.

Comment: @Möoz No, you wouldn't, because real-world physics says that Quicksilver's powers are impossible. This would only be answerable using in-universe evidence to support or refute the claim that Quicksliver experiences an altered sense of temperature while travelling at high speed.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish I don't think this relates directly to the work.  It does not ask for a clarification of an occurrence within the work, or a seminal idea integral to the work.  Rather, it talks about a hypothetical situation that is not present within the work itself, and that the work does not touch on.  The work provides the topic for the hypothetical, but the relationship between the work and the question is not direct.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish This would suppose that every other part of the in-universe physics behaves exactly the same as the real-world, enabling us to answer based off of what we know IRL.

Comment: I did try to apply real world physics to quicksilver but it doesn't work. Even if his body is perfectly accustomed to the insane momentum changes, the momentum due to him arranging guards' arms in the kitchen scene is not conserved. So don't :) And vibrations do not change due to speedy objects.

Answer (score 1):

## You are thinking about this all wrong

When Quicksilver runs, he tastes what they were cooking, not because he is slowing down the air around him, but because his senses are sped-up. Quicksilver can both move and think faster than a standard human being... which is honestly something he would need to be able to avoid death-by-obstacle while running at such high speeds.

Also, when any object moves, it displaces air. Move fast enough, and you will compress a layer of air in-front of yourself, which increases its density, which creates drag and heating and is why people *used* to think it was impossible to break the sound barrier. It is also why a [baseball traveling at 90% C](https://what-if.xkcd.com/1/) (C is the speed of light) would create a fusion bomb that would vaporize a city. While Quicksilver seems to ignore the effects of this through unstated reasons (possibly just brute-force), the compressed-air layer still contains whatever it had in it. That would concentrate the scent of what was being cooked in the kitchen, making it more noticeable.

So, it is not that Quicksilver *cools down* the rest of the universe when he is moving (quite the opposite, in-fact). It is, frankly, <s>mostly</s> *almost entirely* due to Quicksilver's far-enhanced senses and a tiny-bit due to air compression effects at Mach speed (**not** to be confused with Mach Effects, which are related to Relativity) that he can smell what they are cooking in the kitchen.

Comment: Ohh okay, that actually makes more sense, thank you for answering.